# Linear operator on sequences $M_y$ given by $M_y(x) = (y_jx_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ preserves $l^p$ iff $y \in l^{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $y = (y_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ be a fixed sequence. For each sequence $x = (x_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ define a new sequence $M_yx := (y_jx_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$.
Then $M_y$ is a linear operator on the space of all sequences in $\mathbb{K}$.
Prove that TFAE:

i) $M_y(l^p) \subset l^p$ and $M_y$ is a bounded operator
ii) $y \in l^{\infty}$

I showed the direction ii) $\implies$ i) using Hölder. But have no idea for the opposite direction.

Comment: (ii) $\implies$ (i) is even easier. You just need to use the bound $|y_j x_j |^p \le \| y\|_\infty^p |x_j|^p$ which holds for all $j$.

Comment: @User8128 I am sorry this was actually the implication I already showed with hölder using your argument. I edited the post

Comment: My edit was for the typo $x_y$ in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $y \notin l^\infty$, then there is sequence $k_i$ such that $|y_{k_i}| > 2^{i}$.

Let $x_j = 2^{-i}$ if $j = k_i$ and $x_j = 0$ otherwise.

Then $x \in l^p$: $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty |x_j|^p = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-ip} < \infty$, but $M_y(x) \notin l^p$ as it has infinitely many coordinates with absolute value of $1$.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, if $M_y$ is a bounded operator on $\ell^p$ then for each $n$ let $e(n)=(e(n)_j)_j$ where $e(n)_n=1$ and where $e(n)_j=0 $ if $j\ne n. $Then $e(n)\in\ell^p $ with $\|e(n)\|_p=1$. So $\infty>\|M_y\|\ge \sup _n\|M_y(e(n))\|=\sup_n|y_n|.$